# Scat identification from northern New Jersey

Tags: united-states, scat-identification

Can you please help me identify what is leaving these piles in my detached garage in Northern New Jersey? In case the photo doesn't do it justice, the scat is in piles, against the exterior walls, seems wet, very dark, slightly squiggly, and consistently in the same place despite me removing the piles.

We also have some field mice in the garage, but I know this isn't them. There are several other piles like this.

[image]

Comment: What sort of size are we looking at here?
Not an ID by any means, but rats and some other members of the rodents (but not mice) leave scat in piles consistently.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [raccoon latrine](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/baylisascaris/resources/raccoonlatrines.pdf) ([and here](https://www.delta-optimist.com/opinion/blogs/blog-skunk-and-raccoon-latrines-1.23613055)) to me.  We don't have skunks in my area, but perhaps you do. It could be that. In either case I'd be careful around it and try to find a way to discourage the animals from continuing to use it.